# Inconsistent NSTextField Cursor (macOS, Swift)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, cursor, nstextfield

I'm writing a menu bar app that requires a search bar. I did the followind steps:

1. dragged a menu into the storyboard (like this:

[image: Menu])

2. created a custom view and added a textfield
   [image]
3. Using this line of code to relaced the menu item `Search Bar` with the custom view:

   `itemSearch.view = viewSearchBar`

The result was not satisfactory. Sometimes, when I move my cursor onto the NSTextField, the result is like this:

[image]

which is normal. And in these cases, this is what happens when I click the NSTextField:

[image]

However, other times, just relaunching the app without any change of the code, the results (with the cursor hovering above the NSTextField) look like this:

[image]

And the result will be like this when I click my mouse:

[image]

I am really frustrated by this issue, and after two hours of trying, I just want to know the answer...

Please! any ideas?